# How is $A \implies B$ different from $B \implies A$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, logic

For instance

If my TA is good, then I will go to class.  $A \implies B$

If I go to class, then my TA is good. $B \implies A$

I understand that $A \implies B$ is different from $B \implies A$ and they have different truth tables.  But I don't get it.  Exactly what is the difference between those two statements? They are the same!

Comment: You write in the same paragraph that you understand that the two statements are different and that they are the same. You seem to have a problem with logic!

Comment: Going to class does not cause the TA to be good. It has to do with what causes what.

Comment: Do you see that the statements "If I have cheated on my taxes, then I am going to jail" and "If I am going to jail, then I have cheated on my taxes" are different? They make completely different claims. The first (in theory) is true, but the second is not true. You can be jailbound for (say) murder even if you paid your taxes.

Comment: @MPW: Not if you're Al Capone!

Comment: @AsafKaragila: If you're Al Capone, you've been dead for decades

Comment: @MPW: I think that I know enough about AC to argue otherwise.

Comment: I wonder how this person would deal with "if and only if" statements where the implications are each way.

Comment: They are the same in the sense that they are both saying if the LHS is true then the RHS is true, no more than that

Comment: @AsafKaragila: I won't dispute your expertise about AC, if you mean what I *think* you mean ;)

Comment: @LiuGang: That's an interesting take on the question. Sometimes we take for granted what the idea of "sameness" means. The classic topological example of the doughnut and the coffee cup is the same sort of thing--it all depends on your perspective, doesn't it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are *conditional statements* that differ because the location of their propositional variables. 
If we know $A$ and $B$ beforehand then the two sentences $A\rightarrow B$, $B\rightarrow A$ are certainly not the same--as you saw with truth tables. 
Here is an example: Let $A$ be "I get wet", $B$ be "I'm taking a shower". 
 
Look what $A\rightarrow B$ says:

> If **I get wet** then I'm taking a shower

which is not necessarily a true implication given the premises. You could get wet from being in the rain, at the water park, etc.

As for $B\rightarrow A$ we have:

> If **I'm taking a shower** then I get wet.

Given the premises, this statement is true. Maybe the above example is silly, but, in the end, the location of the **variables** causes the sentences to have different truth table values. 
If $A$ is true and $B$ is false, then $B\rightarrow A$ if true, and $A\rightarrow B$ is false, regardless of what $A$ and $B$ really say as propositional variables, so they are different statements just in light of their different truth values.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example.

$A \implies B$: "If it is raning, then the ground is wet."

$B \implies A$: "If the ground is wet, then it is raining."

Now suppose someone took a hose and sprayed the ground with it.  Do you see why the first statement is true, but the second is false?  If you see this, you must believe the two statements are different.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = $ "I live in Canada" and let $B = $ "I live in North America". Then $A \implies B$ is true, since all Canadians are North Americans. But $B \implies A$ can be false, since not all North Americans are Canadian. For example, you could live in USA (which makes $B$ true but $A$ false).

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be a random real number. Let $A$ be the statement "$x > 1$". Let $B$ be the statement "$x>2$"

Then $B \implies A$ (if $x>2$ then certainly $x>1$, but it is not true that  $A \implies B$ (e.g. $x=1.5$: since $1<x<2$)

---

$A \implies B$ means: *if* A is true *then* B is true. If it is raining then I will get wet.

But it is possible for me to get wet without it raining, so it is not necessarily true that $B\implies A$

Answer (score 0):

They are indeed different. $A \implies B$ means that if $A$ is true, then $B$ must be true. But $B$ can be true without $A$ being true.

But on the other hand $B \implies A$ means that $B$ is ONLY true when $A$ is true. But here $A$ can again be true when $B$ is true.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the following situation: Your TA is good and you don't go to class. Then the first statement is false, but the second is true. How can the statements be the same if in this situation, the first is false, but the second is true?

Answer (score 0):

$x=1\implies x^2=1$

$x^2=1\implies (x=1\space\text{or}\space x=-1)$